# Keras model building - ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_24 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (576, 2)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am attempting to construct a keras model for which I have 576 sample, 4 input variables, and 1 target variable that is either a 1 or 0.  I believe I am having an issue with either the dimension/format of my target, or the dimension of the last layer of my model.  I've hit a wall and could use your assistance.

The first thing I tried was to convert my target variable into a binary numpy array, however when I input the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

n_cols = predictors.shape[1]
target_b = to_categorical(target)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu',input_shape=(n_cols,)  ))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss ='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=   ['accuracy'] )
model.fit(predictors, target_b, validation_split=.3)
```

I get the following error:

```py
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_24 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (576, 2)
```

When I tried to keep my target variable as an integer numpy ndarray, I used sparse_categorical_crossentropy instead, but received this error:

```py
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Received a label value of 1 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1).  Label values: 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
 [[Node: SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits_6/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, Tlabels=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Reshape_13, Cast_30)]
```

I think all I need to do is change either the target variable or model dimensions, however I'm not sure which one to change and I'm not sure how.  I'd greatly appreciate your guidance.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Several ways:

1. Change the last layer to `Dense(2, activation='softmax')`
2. Remove the `to_categorical` line, and use `Dense(2, activation='softmax')` along with `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`
3. Remove the `to_categorical` line, and use `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')` and `loss='binary_crossentropy'`

Answer (score 0):

Your input shape into your Dense layer expects a 1D input, but it looks like the data you want to feed in is 2D.  You can resize your input to `input_shape=(576, 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your last layer should be `Dense(2)`. This is because you target_b matrix must be shape (576,2).